# New identities involving infinite summation of trigonometric functions?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, trigonometry

Lately, I'm trying to prove that $\lim \limits_{n\to\infty} \int_0^\infty \sin(xt)e^{-t}\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{t^k}{k!}dt =\frac{1}{x}$ (for $x\neq$ zeros of $\sin(x)$) by using mellin transform of $f(t)=\sin(xt)e^{-t}$, to be specific, $\int_0^\infty t^{s-1}\sin(xt)e^{-t}dt = \frac{\Gamma(s)\sin(s\tan^{-1}(x))}{(x^{2}+1)^{\frac{s}{2}}}$. After dividing $\Gamma(s)$, summing up on both sides and changing the variable, I got the following equation( needed to be proven): $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(k\tan^{-1}(x))}{(x^2+1)^{\frac{k}{2}}}=\frac{1}{x}$. I noticed that $\tan^{-1}(x)=\cos^{-1}({(x^{2}+1)^{-\frac{1}{2}}})$, so after substitution, this is the equivalent equation: $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \sin((k+1)x)\cos(x)^k = \csc(x)$. I have worked a lot and I found some other equations (with the assumption that the equation above is true):
$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \cos((k+2)x)\cos(x)^{k}= -1$, $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \cos(kx)\cos(x)^{k}= 1$
By using those equations, with the formula $(\cos(x)+i\sin(x))^n=\cos(nx)+i\sin(nx)$, I could form a geometric series which visually proves that my assumption is true. But the problem is I actually guessed the answer first, means that my whole work is just a circular reasoning without a proof.
I'm wondering if this identity was discovered and proven before because I can't find them in public discussions. By the way, could you help me prove this?

Any helps will be respected. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Let's prove $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \cos(kx)\cos^k(x) = 1$.
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \mathrm{e}^{ikx}\cos^k(x) &= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\mathrm{e}^{ikx}\sum_{r=0}^{k} \binom{k}{r}2^{-k}\mathrm{e}^{ikx-2irx} \\
&= \sum_{r=0}^{\infty}\left( \sum_{k=r}^{\infty}\binom{k}{r}\left( \frac{\mathrm{e}^{2ix}}{2}\right)^k \right)\mathrm{e}^{-2irx} \\
&= \sum_{r=0}^{\infty} \frac{(\mathrm{e}^{2ix}/2)^{r}}{(1-\mathrm{e}^{2ix}/2)^{r+1}} \mathrm{e}^{-2irx} \\
&= \frac{2}{1-\mathrm{e}^{2ix}} \\
&= 1 + i\cot x
\end{align}
Therefore,
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \cos(kx)\cos^k(x) = \Re\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \mathrm{e}^{ikx}\cos^k(x) = 1.
$$